# Compiled without errors, but does not print anything

Tags: python, printing

This gets compiled without any errors, but does not print anything.

```
def main():
    test = readfile('text.txt')
    print test
    main()

def readfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print lines
        return lines
```

Comment: Python is an [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language); it is not compiled.

Comment: Python is compiled to Bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `main` from outside itself. Otherwise it never gets called.

Basically it could look like this:

```
def main():
    test = readfile('text.txt')
    print test

def readfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print lines
    return lines

main()
```

There is nothing as an entry-point in python, like the main-function in C. A function called main is just another function. Your script will be executed from top to bottom.

---

Or without main:

```
with open(filename) as f: print(f.readlines())
```

Comment: Can I skip defining main and do it like this? 

test = readfile('text.txt')
print test
    
def readfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        print lines
        return lines

Comment: @user3033957 No main needed. See my edit. Just define `readfile` before using it.

Answer (score 1):

main in python (on the end of the file):

```
def main():
    print("main")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```